# BottomNavigationBar covered by body colour in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using the convex_bottom_bar as my bottom navigation bar in Flutter.

With Style: TabStyle.react if I set a colour of the container widget in the body it covers the convex ‘curve’ of the active tab of the navigation bar. If no colour is set the curve can be seen fine.

main.dart

```
import 'package:convex_bottom_bar/convex_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'custom.dart';
import 'game_start.dart';
import 'news.dart';
import 'settings.dart';
import 'share.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MainPage(title: 'Flutter Convex BottomBar Sample'),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainPage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int selectedIndex = 2;
  List<Widget> listWidgets = [
    News(),
    Custom(),
    GameStart(),
    Share(),
    Settings()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: listWidgets[selectedIndex],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
        style: TabStyle.react,
        items: [
          TabItem(icon: Icons.star, title: 'News'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.fact_check, title: 'Custom'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.play_arrow, title: 'Play'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.share, title: 'Share'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.settings, title: 'Settings'),
        ],
        onTap: onItemTapped,
        color: Color(0xFFffc400),
        activeColor: Color(0xFFffc400),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        height: 50,
        initialActiveIndex: 2,
      ),
    );
  }

  void onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

game_start.dart
[image: Game Start image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GameStart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF000000),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Start Game",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22, color: Colors.green),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

news.dart
[image: News image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class News extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF000000),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          "News",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22, color: Colors.green),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you set the `elevation` to `0`?

Comment: I have included code (which I know is not perfect) and screenshots which illustrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I have tried using elevation but it did not help.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting the issue correctly, can you point the issue

Comment: @YeasinSheikh if you look at the Game Start image you can see the convex curve of the bottom navigation bar over the active item (Play) is covered by the black background of the body. The News image shows where a color isn’t defined for the body and the convex curve shows over the active item (News) - this is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The issue is with the plugin. The body container applies to the convex part. You can overcome this issue by stacking the body and convexappbar.

   ```
   class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
     int selectedIndex = 2;
     List<Widget> listWidgets = [
       Container(color: Colors.black,),
       Container(color: Colors.red),
       Container(color: Colors.yellow),
       Container(color: Colors.amber,),
       Container(color: Colors.white,)
     ];

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         body: Stack(
           alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
           children: [
             Container(
               child: listWidgets[selectedIndex],
             ),
             ConvexAppBar(
               style: TabStyle.react,
               items: [
                 TabItem(icon: Icons.star, title: 'News'),
                 TabItem(icon: Icons.fact_check, title: 'Custom'),
                 TabItem(icon: Icons.play_arrow, title: 'Play'),
                 TabItem(icon: Icons.share, title: 'Share'),
                 TabItem(icon: Icons.settings, title: 'Settings'),
               ],
               onTap: onItemTapped,
               color: Color(0xFFffc400),
               activeColor: Color(0xFFffc400),
               backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
               height: 50,
               initialActiveIndex: 2,
               elevation: 5
             )
           ],
         ),
       );
     }

     void onItemTapped(int index) {
       setState(() {
         selectedIndex = index;
       });
     }
   }
   ```
2. The is no visual difference between the bottom navbar and body.
3. black87 doesn't mean it is grey. It is black with an opacity of 87% and the alpha fills based on the body colour. If possible try to switch the colour for the body and bottom navbar.

[image: black87OpacityDifference]

[image: black87 for body color]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is both `GameStart`'s`Container` color and `backgroundColor` of`ConvexAppBar` are black, That's why it makes no difference in our eyes.

If you change the color of the container, you will be alble see the curve,

```dart
class GameStart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 255, 49),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Start Game",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22, color: Colors.green),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case. The background is black while the bar is a dark grey colour. There is an obvious distinction between the two.

Comment: Oh I've just noticed now

Comment: Ok, so I’ve changed the bar and color to two completely separate colours and it works but it doesn’t if both are shades black??

Comment: yes, I am also testing this fact